# jQuery fadeIn or animate when scrolled past a certain point

Tags: jquery, navigation, scroll

So I have a navigation somewhere on my header, when a user scroll pass the navigation I want to minimize it and fadeIn or animate it back as a fixed navigation to the top of page, I made it work with the following jquery code but the issue is that it does the job with css, if I try to replace it with animate, it keeps repeating itself for each pixel it passes.

here is the code:

```
function fixDiv() {

var $cache = $('.stickynav'); 
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 127)

$cache.css({'position': 'fixed','top': '0px','height': '40px'}),
$('#logo img').css({'height': '30px', 'position': 'relative', 'bottom': '10px'}),
$('#main_menu_container').css({'bottom': '40px'});

else                                    
$cache.css({'position': 'relative','top': '0px', 'height': 'auto'}),
$('#logo img').css({'height': 'auto', 'position': 'auto', 'bottom': 'auto'}),
$('#main_menu_container').css({'bottom': 'auto'});
}

$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
fixDiv();
```

[Here is a live jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bsUG/)

Comment: can you make a working demo in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Just added to the question

Comment: what do you want to animate

Comment: the .stickynav , the navigation!

Comment: can you update the fiddle with the animation code

Comment: Just did, but i was hoping to know what's wrong in my code and what's the best approach for achieving this

Comment: checkout http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Q4WK6/2/

Comment: thanks man that's pretty much what im looking for but rather having a fadeIn function, one thing I dont know why you are using that #main_menu_container

Comment: since the selector is used many times it is better to cache that

Comment: alright thanks, leave your comment as an answer so I can choose it as the right one, also if you can tell me how to make it work with fadeIn() I would really appreciate that.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Q4WK6/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function(){
    var isfxd = false, $cache = $('.stickynav'), $ct = $('#main_menu_container'), $img = $('#logo img');

    function fixDiv() {
        var shdfxd = $(window).scrollTop() > 127;

        if (shdfxd && !isfxd) {
            isfxd = true;

            $cache.finish().css({'position': 'fixed'}).animate({'top': '0px','height': '40px'});
            $img.css({'height': '30px', 'position': 'relative', 'bottom': '10px'});
            $ct.css({'bottom': '40px'});
        } else if(isfxd && !shdfxd) {
            isfxd = false;

            $cache.finish().css({'position': 'relative','top': '0px', 'height': 'auto'});
            $img.css({'height': 'auto', 'position': 'auto', 'bottom': 'auto'});
            $ct.css({'bottom': 'auto'});
        }
    }
    $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
    fixDiv();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Q4WK6/)

Note that finish() only works in jquery 1.9 and higher